# What happens when you cash in at level 15?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I finished all the challenges and have the option to "cash in", but I'm afraid I'll lose all the items I have bought so far if I do so.

Does "cashing in" get rid of the items you've bought already?

Comment: I'm level 61 right now. You get new missions and a token.

Answer (score 8):

You don't lose any of the items you've bought, coins collected, level reached, etc.

The only thing that happens is that you receive a random token (viewable on your profile) and you receive a new set of missions, allowing you to level up past level 15 (and earn another random token after the next 15 levels).

Answer (score 0):

Cashing in doesn't make you lose any coins, jetpacks, clothes, etc. When you cash in, you'll get a medal for cashing in and they will give a new set of missions starting from easiest to hardest again, the medal will then end up in your profile and show off what you have achieved! And you can keep cashing in to earn more medals, I am on level 55 or 56 right now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm at level 1583 and nothing hasever happened. It gives new missions and 1 out of 125 badges, wich after youve collected all of them, you'll get duplicates.